# Parsing JSON server side in Java?

Tags: java, json

Client side I have:

```
keyList = ["560", "565", "566"]
```

I need to send it to server with POST request.
So, I decided to use JSON.

```
var jsonString= {keyList:JSON.stringify(keyList)};
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url, 
        data: {"keyList":jsonString},
        dataType: "json"
    });
```

Server side I done:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Controller/parsingJSON", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void parsingJSON(@RequestParam("keyList") String keyList, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request){         
        List<String> listRes= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(keyList.split(",")));
        System.out.println(listRes);
}
```

> listRes = [["560", "565", "566"]]

If I print the first element I get `["560"`

I need the `listRes` was `["560", "565", "566"]` and not `[["560", "565", "566"]]`.

Comment: Nowhere in your code you're parsing the result as JSON, you're just getting a string that you're splitting on commas. Either do the parsing yourself via a JSON library, or get your server side framework to do the parsing for you. What do you use on the server?

Comment: Ah.. Ok. Using ObjectWriter how can I do it?

Comment: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes if you have Jackson

Comment: Please at least include a "?" in your "question". It helps readibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you send JSON string as parameter to `keyList`, you should do it like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url, 
    data: {"keyList":JSON.stringify(keyList)},
    dataType: "json"
});
```

On the server you will get a JSON string, and if you want to deserialize it to object you should manually parse this string.